# VS2010 i am missing a reference

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reference, add-in

using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer;

[image]

unable to find this pls assist
**[update]**

found the dll's in this folders
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\ (in the windows explorer just search for the missing reference and add the .dll)

[image]
**[update]**
Ok my bad i changed the target framework to .Net 4 client profile but have to change to .Net4 framework and the build suceeded

so was unable to resolve this what else i need to do?

This is the ultimate error haunting me
[image]

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is a namespace, not an assembly. You're probably looking for the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SDK.SqlStudio` assembly.

Note that not all assemblies are listed in this dialog. This can for instance be found in the (Program Files) `Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\` directory, you can use the `Browse` functionality to add a reference.

Comment: tks for this i found the .dll and no errors i have added some screenshots and i am still getting errors please see the updated question..tks

Comment: tks for the help added the answer in the question. Btw one silly question i keep getting the last image in my question even though i followed what the writer said to do by disabling the pinvoke thing what is the problem?

Comment: @JackyBoi, since it isn't really clear what you're trying to do I cannot assist in this regard. It seems that the program somehow starts `SMSS.EXE` with invalid command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this blog entry useful:
https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/sql-server-2012-extended-events-add-in-to-manage-2008r2-instances/